# How large can the working die size in a wide PDIP package be?

Tags: integrated-circuit, packages, die

What is the maximum die size for a 0.6" wide Plastic DIP package?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Have you done any research on this? Please provide some additional information rather than only a one-line question in your post. See [Help/How do I ask a good question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's a straight forward question. It's as detailed as it could be.

Comment: Reference, the package outline is coveted by the standards of JEDEC MS-011. Not sure if the standard dictates internals as well, as you have to pay to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends completely on:

1. Design of the package outline
2. Design of the package carrier
3. Whether the package carrier supports multilevel interconnect
4. Design of the package lead frame
5. Number of pins on the DIP package
6. Length to width ratio of the integrated circuit chip

So as it stands there is no way to answer your question as written. If you are curious about any specific package technology then **go ask the manufacturer**. Lead frame manufacturers are probably the best place for you to start.

Comment: Non-Answer that boils down to "go ask someone/somewhere else".

Comment: @Passerby - You are welcome to your opinion but this is an answer in that I provide solid reasons for what is involved in the consideration of the die size. Clearly the OP is completely unaware of these factors. Maybe you are too.

Comment: Question was solely for precalculations of an idea. I hoped, there is at least approximate public information about. What i can estimate, its 130 mm2, and will be good any more precise estimation. As of manufacturer(s) - well, i found only one, MOSIS - demand, i should have a company, or i should be a university student, or they dont allow me to complete a registration. If you are an expert in the question, and you tell me, it is an industrial secret, and no one have rights to know it without pay the bill for, then i accept it as answer.